# Removing all rows from a table using JPA

Tags: java, database, jpa

I want to remove all rows from a specific table using JPA.

What I did:

```
public class EmptyBomTables extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "xxx")
    public EntityManager em;

    @Resource
    UserTransaction utx;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        Query q1 = em.createQuery("DELETE FROM BomModule");
        Query q2 = em.createQuery("DELETE FROM BomItem");
        Query q3 = em.createQuery("DELETE FROM ItemModuleConnection");
        Query q4 = em.createQuery("DELETE FROM ModuleConnection");

        try {
            utx.begin();
        } catch (NotSupportedException | SystemException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        q1.executeUpdate();
        q2.executeUpdate();
        q3.executeUpdate();
        q4.executeUpdate();

        try {
            utx.commit();
        } catch (SecurityException | IllegalStateException | RollbackException | HeuristicMixedException | HeuristicRollbackException | SystemException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
   09:30:30,197 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/SSIS2].[EmptyBomTables]] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Servlet.service() for servlet EmptyBomTables threw exception: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractQueryImpl.executeUpdate(AbstractQueryImpl.java:96) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.QueryNonTxInvocationDetacher.executeUpdate(QueryNonTxInvocationDetacher.java:80) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at com.sicap.ssis2.bom.EmptyBomTables.doGet(EmptyBomTables.java:50) [classes:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:397) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]

09:30:30,218 ERROR [org.jboss.as.txn] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) JBAS010152: APPLICATION ERROR: transaction still active in request with status 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Doesn't this: `TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query` give you an indication?

Comment: It says that a transaction is required, that's why I added utx.begin and utx.commit

Comment: And `utx` is what? Also, why separate `try-catch` blocks?

Comment: How is `utx` set up, can u show that code?

Comment: Added the code above.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That was the problem, everything has to be in the same try/catch:

```
try {

    utx.begin();

    Query q3 = em.createQuery("DELETE FROM ItemModuleConnection");
    Query q4 = em.createQuery("DELETE FROM ModuleConnection");
    Query q1 = em.createQuery("DELETE FROM BomModule");
    Query q2 = em.createQuery("DELETE FROM BomItem");

    q1.executeUpdate();
    q2.executeUpdate();
    q3.executeUpdate();
    q4.executeUpdate();

    utx.commit();
} catch (NotSupportedException | SystemException | SecurityException | IllegalStateException | RollbackException | HeuristicMixedException | HeuristicRollbackException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Since the question used `createQuery`, I think your answer should also use `createQuery` instead of `createNativeQuery`

Comment: You can cast all those exceptions to the native type Exception. It's way shorter. 
Just type ``} catch (Exception exception) { .... } ``.