# JPA delete all not working on Google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa

I have the following code and am trying to delete all the categories but it is throwing me illegal argument exception. I am using google app engine.

```
public void deleteCategories() {
  EntityManager em = EMFService.get().createEntityManager();



  try {

      em.getTransaction().begin();
      Query q = em.createQuery("DELETE FROM Category cat");
      q.executeUpdate();
      em.getTransaction().commit();
      System.out.println("All records are deleted.");
  } catch(Exception ex){
      System.out.println(ex.toString());

  }
  finally {
      if (em.getTransaction().isActive()) {
          em.getTransaction().rollback();
      }
  }
  }
```

After running this code i am getting javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Illegal argument the full stack trace is as follows
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cross-group transaction need to be explicitly specified, see TransactionOptions.Builder.withXGfound both Element {
  type: "Category"
  name: "1"
}
 and Element {
  type: "Category"
  name: "100223"
}

```
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper.translateError(DatastoreApiHelper.java:39)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper$1.convertException(DatastoreApiHelper.java:76)
at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:94)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl$10.get(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:622)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl$10.get(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:618)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FutureHelper$TxnAwareFuture.get(FutureHelper.java:171)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FutureHelper.getInternal(FutureHelper.java:71)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FutureHelper.quietGet(FutureHelper.java:32)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl.delete(DatastoreServiceImpl.java:128)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.WrappedDatastoreService.delete(WrappedDatastoreService.java:184)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.DatastoreQuery.wrapEntityQueryResult(DatastoreQuery.java:417)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.DatastoreQuery.performExecute(DatastoreQuery.java:343)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.JPQLQuery.performExecute(JPQLQuery.java:176)
at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.executeQuery(Query.java:1789)
at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.executeWithMap(Query.java:1693)
at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAQuery.executeUpdate(JPAQuery.java:124)
... 28 more
```

Comment: I overcame this exception by enabling xg transactions for gae by putting  <property name="datanucleus.appengine.datastoreEnableXGTransactions" value="true"/> in persitence.xml but now i am getting operating on too many entity groups in a single transaction. and i think this is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16675041/gae-jpa-xg-transactions-too-many-entity-groups-exception

Answer (score 0):

What does **cat** do in your query? I guess that's the error, because the general query pattern for deleting rows is as follows, there's no need of using an alias:

> DELETE * FROM mytablename

OR

> DELETE FROM mytablename

Maybe you can check further in this question already answered -> [Removing all rows from a table using JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15084550/removing-all-rows-from-a-table-using-jpa)

Answer (score 0):

1. There's no need to use alias in `delete` statement, so you can remove `cat` from the JPQL.
2. You should only roll back the transaction in the `catch` block part.
3. You should **always** close the `EntityManager` after using it, usually in `finally` block.
4. You're only printing the first line of the stacktrace. This is a bad practice. Instead, print the stacktrace in the common output. Or even better, use a logger that handles log files and exception printing for you.

Here's how the code should look like

```
public void deleteCategories() {
    EntityManager em = EMFService.get().createEntityManager();
    try {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        Query q = em.createQuery("DELETE FROM Category");
        q.executeUpdate();
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        System.out.println("All records are deleted.");
    } catch(Exception ex){
        if (em.getTransaction().isActive()) {
            em.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
        //should be changed for something like
        //log.error("Error while deleting all the categories", ex);
        ex.printStacktrace(System.out);
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Luiggi but after using the above method i am getting SEVERE: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: FROM clause of query has class com.myapp.model.Category but no alias